# Is there "3g only" mode in cellular settings in Windows Phone 10 Technical Preview

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cellular-data, 3g

I was wondering if there is "3G only" mode in Windows Phone 10 Technical Preview. I was thinking of trying it.

Comment: Do you want just to disable WiFi, or not "some" mobile connection systems (For example, to do you consider HSPA 3G?)

Answer (score -3):

Settings> About> Reset. 3g/2g working.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information?